# Passar dois parâmetros - ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Preciso passar dois parâmetros para uma página, quando eu estou tentando passar um só, eu faço desta forma:

```
<a asp-page="/ContaReceber/Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id;" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Editar</a>
```

Tentei passar algo como:

```
<a asp-page="/ContaReceber/Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id; @item.PessoaId" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Editar</a>
```

Tentei colocar somente vírgula, nomear o parâmetro, porém não dá certo, como posso passar mais de um parâmetro para a page.

Comment: Você tem que passar um asp-route para cada para parametro.
<a asp-controller="/ContaReceber/Edit" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-route-username="@item.UserName">Edit</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque `asp-route-` o nome do parâmetro de rota, ***exemplo***:

```
<a asp-page="/ContaReceber/Edit" 
   asp-route-id="@item.Id" 
   asp-route-PessoaId="item.PessoaId" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
Editar
</a>
```

Vale lembrar que cada parâmetro de rota são separadas e no final não precisa colocar `;` igual está na pergunta. Se você tiver mais parâmetro é só adicionar como está no exemplo.

Comment: Desse jeito dá certo, só que tem um probleminha rs, quando eu passo este parâmetro, é para ele retornar para outra página, onde que seria  http://localhost:55695/Pessoa/Edit?id=2 só que na hora de retornar, ele retorna assim, como posso alterar? http://localhost:55695/Pessoa/Edit?PessoaId=3

Comment: Eu sinceramente não entendi o que aconteceu @marianac_costa você poderia explicar exemplificando? (só lembrando que a resposta colocada a você é assim que funciona, talvez falte colocar uma rota !!! na sua `page`)

Comment: Desculpe, fiz confusão aqui, agora consegui entender, me ajudou muito, obrigado.